# Is my proof of equivalence valid?

Tags: probability

Let $A \succeq B$ be defined as $A$ is at least as probable as $B$. $A \succ B$ is defined as $A\succeq B$ and $B \nsucceq A$, i.e. $A$ is strictly more probable than $B$. $A \approx B$ is defined as $A\succeq B$ and $B \succeq A$, i.e. $A$ is equiprobable as $B$. An axiom that $\succeq$ obeys is

**Additivity**: If $A \cap C=B \cap C=\emptyset$, then $A \succeq B$ if and only if $A \cup C \succeq B \cup C$.

I would like to prove that the following two constraints on $\succeq$ are equivalent.

**Regularity**:$\forall A(A \neq \emptyset \rightarrow A \succ \emptyset)$

**Regularity 2**: $\forall A(A \neq \Omega \rightarrow \Omega \succ A)$

Here’s my proof. Assume that **Regularity** is true first. Assume that **Regularity 2** is false for reductio. This means that $\exists A (A\neq \Omega \land \Omega \nsucc A)$. Let $a$ be this $A$. So $a \neq \Omega \land \Omega \approx a$. Since $a \neq \Omega$, the complement of $a^c \neq \emptyset$. By **Regularity**, $a^c \succ \emptyset$. This means $\emptyset \nsucceq a^c$. By **Additivity**, $a= \emptyset \cup a \nsucceq a^c \cup a = \Omega$. Since $\Omega \approx a$, $a \succeq \Omega$. Contradiction. So **Regularity 2** must be true. The same steps can be used to prove **Regularity** while assuming **Regularity 2**. Therefore, **Regularity** is equivalent to **Regularity 2**.

Is my proof valid? My worry is that I used **Additivity**. Is this okay?

Edit: typo in **Additivity**

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the additivity axiom. If $A \cap C=B \cap C=\emptyset$, then trivially $A \cap C \succeq B \cap C$, since $P(A \cap C)=P(B \cap C)=0$.

Comment: Oh right. Instead of intersection, it should be union.